# Change namespace of child element using xsl

Tags: xslt

How do I replace the namespace of child elements in an xml?
For example I have this source file:

```
<ns:Parent xmlns:ns="http://test.com">
  <ns:Name>John</ns:Name>
  <ns:Country>Japan</ns:Country>
  <ns:Contact>9999999</ns:Contact>
</ns:Parent>
```

My output should be like this:

```
<ns:Parent xmlns:ns="http://test.com">
  <ns1:Name xmlns:ns1="http://development.com">John</ns1:Name>
  <ns:Country>Japan</ns:Country>
  <ns:Contact>9999999</ns:Contact>
</ns:Parent>
```

So basically All the other fields aside from Name were not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start with the [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), to handle copying all the nodes you don't want to change

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, just add a template to match `ns:Name`, where you create a new node in your required namespace instead (where `ns1` is defined on the `xsl:stylesheet` element)

```
<xsl:template match="ns:Name">
    <ns1:Name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ns1:Name>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:ns="http://test.com"
                xmlns:ns1="http://development.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="ns:Name">
        <ns1:Name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ns1:Name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'll try this out!